# Records missing in data loader export

Tags: data-loader

I am exporting the data from an object with the credentials of an user who has read and edit access to that object. The object OWD is public read write. The user can see all the records of the object when logged in.
When exporting the data in the object - I am obtaining only few records.
Please tell me any reason as to why this is so. Is there any security factor I have over looked when using data loader.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can he access all records if he has ONLY read and edit access at profile level. He atleast needs "View All" permission to access all records created by others. Are there any sharing rules?

Comment: Can you share the query which is generated when using Dataloader?